# How to get specific Java output stored in echo string of bat file and then use it to trigger another jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, executable-jar

I have a jar file which I'm triggering through batch file like this:

```
 SET JAVA_EXE="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java.exe"
 %JAVA_EXE% -jar TimeStampVerification.jar"
```

These are some of the outputs I get from running it[image]

After this output I want to save the highlighted output in variable to perform If operation. If this output displays, I need to trigger another jar file.

Till now, I tried using :

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%o in ('java -jar TimeStampVerification.jar %1') do set output=%%o
echo %output%
pause
```

However, it is not showing output. Please help.

Comment: What about setting the output to a variable and using grep?

Comment: How can i do that? I tried finding it but was not successful

Comment: There are unbalanced quotes in your first code fragment. Anyway, the output might be returned at _STDERR_ since it looks like an error message; append `2>&1` (or `2^>^&1` in the `for /F` loop) to redirect _STDERR_ to _STDOUT_, wo it can be captured by `for /F`…

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
....'java -jar TimeStampVerification.jar %1^|findstr /b /L /c:"Timestamp"' ....
```

which should select the line starting (/b) with the literal string (/L) specified.

Please clarify what the output shown actually was. Telling us it's not showing what you expect doesn't contribute to our knowledge of the issue - after all, if it showed what you expected, you wouldn't be asking. What, then, did it show?

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. Once you find the string, how are you storing into variable?

Comment: if you append the extra instruction `^|findstr /b /L /c:"Timestamp"` to your `java` instruction as shown, the string `Timestamp on Websphere....` should be assigned to `%%o` and then to `output` by the `set`. It should then be displayed by the `echo`.